# file handling in xna

Tags: xna

Icreated txt file through IsolatedStorageFile in xna. I m not getting the path where this file is store. I want to read this file . Please help if anyone knows.
I am going from this screen (where this file is create) and returning back to again this screen.Bt getting this error. Operation not permited on Isolated storagefilestream.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will save an `int` into the Isolated Storage, and then read it back out in the `loadScore` method.

```
private void saveScore(int score)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[highScoreTag] = score;

    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}

private int loadScore()
{
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(highScoreTag))
    {
        return (int)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[highScoreTag];
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Also, check out Nick Gravelyn's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/23/storage-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).